# Do email forms need to be santized before sending?

Tags: security, email

I have a client that keeps getting reports from godaddy's "websiteprotection.com" stating how the website is insecure.

> Your website contains pages that do not properly sanitize
>   visitor‑provided input to make sure it contains no malicious content
>   or scripts. Cross‑site scripting vulnerabilities let malicious users
>   execute arbitrary HTML or script code in another visitor's browser.
>
> Output:
>
> The request string used to detect this flaw was :
>   /cross_site_scripting.​nasl.asp The output was :
>   HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r Date: Wed, 21 Mar 2012 08:12:02 GMT\r Server:
>   Apache\r X-Pingback:http://​CLIENTSWEBSITE.com/​xmlrpc.php\r Expires:
>   Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT\r Cache-Control: no-cache,
>   must-revalidate, max-age=0\r Pragma: no-cache\r Set-Cookie:
>   PHPSESSID=​1jsnhuflvd59nb4trtquston50; path=/\r Last-Modified: Wed, 21
>   Mar 2012 08:12:02 GMT\r Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100\r Connection:
>   Keep-Alive\r Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=UTF-8\r \r

```
<div id="contact-form" class="widget"><form action="http://​CLIENTSWEBSITE.c
     om/<script>cross_site_​scripting.nasl</script>.asp" id="contactForm"
     meth od="post">
```

It looks like it has an issue with the contact form. All the contact form does is posts an ajax request to the same page, and than a PHP script mails the data (no database stuff).

Is there any a security issues here? Any ideas on how I can satisfy the security scanner?

Here is the form and script:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getCurrentUrl(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="" class="txt requiredField name" />
    //Some more text inputs

    <input type="hidden" name="sendadd" id="sendadd" value="<?php echo $emailadd ; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" /><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
    // Some initial JS validation, if that passes an ajax post is made to the script below

    //If the form is submitted
    if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    //Check captcha 
if (isset($_POST["captchaPrefix"])) {

$capt = new ReallySimpleCaptcha();
$correct = $capt->check( $_POST["captchaPrefix"], $_POST["Captcha"] );
if( ! $correct ) { echo false; die(); } else {
$capt->remove( $_POST["captchaPrefix"] );
}

}


$dateon = $_POST["dateon"]; 
$ToEmail = $_POST["sendadd"]; 
$EmailSubject = 'Contact Form Submission from ' . get_bloginfo('title'); 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["Email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["Email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 

$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["Name"]."<br>"; 

$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email Address: ".$_POST["Email"]."<br>"; 

$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Phone: ".$_POST["Phone"]."<br>"; 

if ($dateon == "on") {$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Date: ".$_POST["Date"]."<br>";}

$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Message: ".$_POST["Comments"]."<br>"; 

mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 

echo true; die(); 


}
```

Comment: Why is it `<script>cross_site_​scripting.nasl</script>.asp`?

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom That code is not in the actual live form, its from the security report. it seems the security scanner injected that, which is why is thinks the form is insecure.

Comment: @levi Wait, is the e-mail TO address passed from the contact form? Because that's pretty dangerous for a start. Could you post the whole form, too?

Comment: @Dan dangerous from a spam standpoint, or site security?

Comment: @levi Potentially both. Firstly, if I'm understanding your script / form correctly - it'd be fairly trivial to use your set to send loads of spam. Secondly, you're putting unchecked data straight into the mail() function. Not to much an issue with the $MESSAGE_BODY variable, but I'd worry about putting things directly into the header and the to address.

Comment: I understand Its currently not spam protected well. Say someone did put malicious content into the header, worst case scenario is spam no? is there any way this can lead to a "Cross‑site scripting vulnerability" as godaddy puts it?

Comment: @levi **From what you've posted here**, no, I don't understand GoDaddy's complaint about the submission form. But you have pretty major problems with your PHP script. And I don't know if worst case is SPAM, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what's going on here, but are they complaining about the data going from the form to the "http://website/script.asp" without being checked?

Because, if so, then that's just ridiculous because even if you *chose* to do some JavaScript / other client-side checking, one should never rely on it. All the sanitisation should be done server side, which I presume it is?

Could you post the original script for clarity?

Comment: Added the script. There is no sanitation being done at the moment. Aside from spam issues, is there a need to sanitize it?

Comment: The first time you XSS a customer off into an infection server will be a good test of their loyalty to you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a security risk because it's possible to type `<script>cross_site_​scripting.nasl</script>`.asp into a form (or a hidden element), and have it appear on your pages. That lets other websites inject arbitary code into your website. If you're *just* using a contact form and have no user login or cookies, then this is just a spam risk.

(Post the HTML/PHP which generates the form, and this may become clearer)

Comment: There are no cookies or db stuff being done. To add the script permanently on the page they would need to access the sites database. Otherwise its like adding it in firebug no?

Comment: Yes, it's temporary. For the moment, it only presents the security risk of annoyance. I think it's still worth understanding and fixing it, which is just a question of replacing "<?php echo $this->getCurrentUrl(); ?>" with the form URL in line 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is immediately at risk because you're blindly using $_POST for your email headers. This could allow a person to manipulate the header of the email to send to a wildcard email address, or simply use your form on your server to send spam to others.

With a content type of HTML, you should run `htmlentities()` on the user input ( Assuming you don't really want them to have HTML fire off in an email viewer as mentioned).

Additionally, look into `filter_input()` to ensure the email address they're entering is valid and not header injection.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php